# Compile error: No such file or directory

Tags: file, directory

When I try to compile my code I get this:

```
fatal error: includes.h: No such file or directory.
```

Why is it throwing this error?

This program is supposed to demonstrate linked lists.

```
#include "includes.h"
ListType list[5];
int main()
{
 ListType list[5];
 list[0].value = 0; list[0].next = list+1;
 list[1].value = 10; list[1].next = list+2;
 list[2].value = 20; list[2].next = NULL;
 ListReport(list);
 // Insert an element
 list[3].value = 15; list[3].next = list+2;
 list[1].next = list+3;
 ListReport(list);
 // Remove an element
 list[0].next = list+3;
 ListReport(list);
 return 0;
}
// Report values in linked lisk
void ListReport(ListType *plist)
{
 int nn = 0;
 printf("ListReport\n");
 while(plist != NULL){
 printf("%d, value = %d\n",nn++, plist->value);
 plist = plist->next;
 }
}
/*******************************************************
* includes.h
******************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct entry
 {
 int value;
 struct entry *next;
 } ListType;
 void ListReport(ListType *plist);

// end of includes.h
```

Comment: Is includes.h in the same folder as  main file?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be concatenating your .cpp and .h files in to one. You need to separate them into 2 files.

Like so:

main.cpp

```
#include "includes.h"
ListType list[5];
int main()
{
 ListType list[5];
 list[0].value = 0; list[0].next = list+1;
 list[1].value = 10; list[1].next = list+2;
 list[2].value = 20; list[2].next = NULL;
 ListReport(list);
 // Insert an element
 list[3].value = 15; list[3].next = list+2;
 list[1].next = list+3;
 ListReport(list);
 // Remove an element
 list[0].next = list+3;
 ListReport(list);
 return 0;
}
// Report values in linked lisk
void ListReport(ListType *plist)
{
 int nn = 0;
 printf("ListReport\n");
 while(plist != NULL){
 printf("%d, value = %d\n",nn++, plist->value);
 plist = plist->next;
 }
}
```

includes.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct entry
{
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
} ListType;
void ListReport(ListType *plist);
```

Alternatively you could combine the files like you have and remove the #include statement from the top.

Comment: Try put the typedef statement at the top before you use it